# VS Cordova crashes when stop debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, ripple

has anyone had this problem?

Basically, using VS2015 - when we try and debug using the ripple emulator then try and stop debugging, VS freeze's and the following error is shown.

[image: VS Error Cordova Error]

Has anyone experienced this? I have searched the ENTIRE internet and just cant seem to find anything!

Comment: Thanks for using VS 2105. Does this happen when you 'run' (CTRL+F5) to Ripple or is this only during debug? We havent received any reports for this issue, but I would like to know more.

Comment: @SubhagOak  It is always happens using any debug method and is consistant with our development team - Send me a PM and we can discuss more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with Telerik AppBuilder extension being installed along side using a visual studio 2015 cordova project. There seems to be a conflict. We've removed AppBuilder and this issue seems to have gone and cancelling debugging is much more responsive.